# Invalid use of group function while group by size

Tags: mysql, group-by

i try to select all users who have a higher document size then 50.
So i group the size column in the database, but i get this error: "Invalid use of group function"
What do i do wrong?

```
$sql_select_document = "SELECT gebruikers.id AS userId, 
                                        documenten.upload_user_id AS uuid
            FROM documenten 
            JOIN gebruikers
            ON documenten.upload_user_id = gebruikers.id
        WHERE SUM(documenten.size) > 50
            AND gebruikers.id = '".$fetch_users['id']."'";

$query_select_document = mysql_query($sql_select_document) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: GROUP BY ... HAVING SUM(...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use a HAVING clause after the group by.

So your query might look like

```
SELECT gebruikers.id AS userId, 
       documenten.upload_user_id AS uuid
            FROM documenten 
            JOIN gebruikers
            ON documenten.upload_user_id = gebruikers.id
        WHERE gebruikers.id = '".$fetch_users['id']."'.
GROUP BY gebruikers.id, documenten.upload_user_id
   HAVING SUM(documenten.size) > 50'";
```